# How to connect RFID Attendance Machine to PHP MySQL web application?

Tags: php

Currently I am developing a school project using PHP/MySQL. In that project I want to fetch attendance records from a RFID Attendance Machine.

I've searched many sites, but I am not able to find proper solution.

Comment: What outputs does your RFID machine have? What interface does it use to a computer - USB? Please edit these details into your question. Bear in mind that without this detail, we can only guess how you should proceed.

Comment: Also, note that this is a broad question, and thus is not suitable for Stack Overflow. We answer programming questions here, but your problem is a whole project.